# Using foreign characters in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, character-encoding, hebrew

i tried to import some data(csv file) to R but it is in Hebrew and sadly the text is transformed to this for example : ׳¨׳׳™׳“׳”    ׳₪׳¡׳™׳›׳™׳׳˜׳¨׳™׳” ׳׳ ׳¢׳¦׳׳׳™ 43.61
3   ׳™׳¢׳¨׳™ ׳׳‘׳™׳‘    ׳₪׳¡׳™׳›׳™׳׳˜׳¨׳™׳” ׳׳ ׳¢׳¦׳׳׳™ 45.00
4   ׳׳’׳¨׳‘ ׳׳ ׳˜׳•׳    ׳₪׳¡׳™׳›׳™׳׳˜׳¨׳™׳” ׳׳ ׳¢׳¦

what can i do to keep the hebrew text ? thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

For reading csv files with Hebrew characters, you can use `readr` package, which is a part of the `tidyverse` package. This package has a lot of utilities for language encoding and localization like `guess_encoding` and `locale`.
Try code below:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(readr)
locale("he")
guess_encoding(file = "path_to_your_file", n_max = 10000, threshold = 0.2) //replace with your data
df <- read_csv(file = "path_to_your_file", locale = locale(date_names = "he", encoding = "UTF-8")) //replace with your data
```

`guess_encoding` will help you to determine which encoding is more optimal for your file (for example, `UTF-8`, `ISO 8859-8`, `Windows-1255`, etc.); this function calculates the probability of a file of being encoded in several encodings. You should use the encoding with the highest probability.